# How to overwrite CSS style in Primefaces AutoComplete?

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

As far as I know the `AutoComplete` component generates a `span` element with an `input` inside. I want to link said `input` to a certain class in my stylesheet so it can be just like the second and third normal input fields here:

[Link to imgur, I can't embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6ODQ.png)

The problem is I can't use the `style` or `styleClass` attributes since they seem to only affect the `span` tag.

Some code:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{requestForm.recipientString}"
                completeMethod="#{requestForm.recipientAutoComplete}"
                widgetVar="forWidget" minQueryLength="3" scrollHeight="200"
                styleClass="inputTop" />


<p:inputText value="#{requestForm.reference}"
                widgetVar="referenceWidget" styleClass="inputTop" />
```

As you can see I use the `inputTop` class on both components but then the `AutoComplete` places it on the `span` tag.

Is there a way to fix this? I don't see any other attribute in the guide to accomplish this -since the `panelStyleClass` only affects the autocomplete panel- and I don't want to edit the theme itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF is in this regard nothing more than an html generator, and just like with plain html, there is no need to have a class *on* an element to be able to use it to style something. If the class is on the parent or one of it's ancestors, you can use it to style things as well. This is all basic css and is described on thousands of sites on the internet.

```
.inputTop input {
    background-color: red;
}
```

is an example. You might need to play with [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to get it to actually override possible existing style.

Comment: That's true! The solution was quite obvious but somehow it never came to me. Thank you.